# Forecasting seasonality factor using statsmodels - X13 ARIMA

Tags: python-3.x, statistics, statsmodels

I possess a weekly set of data that I combined into monthly series for the purpose of utilizing statsmodels' X13 ARIMA. By employing the provided settings, I can obtain seasonally adjusted data. Nevertheless, it is crucial for me to have the capability to forecast the seasonal factor, referred to as 'Seasonality(forcast)', in order to adjust my weekly data when it becomes available.

The program only returns the forecast seasonality adjusted values, Y(forecast)

Note: Y(forecast) = Trend (forecast) * Seasonality (forecast) * Irregular (forecast)

Below is the settings I have:

```
result = sm.tsa.x13_arima_analysis(df_mth1,
                                       maxorder=(2, 1),
                                       maxdiff=(2, 1),
                                       exog=None,
                                       log=True,
                                       outlier=True,
                                       trading=True,
                                       forecast_periods=1,
                                       start=None,
                                       print_stdout=False,
                                       x12path=XPATH,
                                       prefer_x13=True)
```

Many Thanks
L

I have read the whole x13 menu from the FED consensus. Looking at the statsmodel x13 arima, seem like there is no way to get the seasonality factor. I tried to put in SEATS spec into it, but it doesnt allow me. Is it because the python statsmodel could not replicate the FED consensus x13 software?